# Query Empty Exception in MySql while insert record in table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to insert record in table with `createQuery()` in MySql,But it gives me Query was `empty()` exception

**Code :**

```
String queryString="INSERT INTO Mytable (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) Select 111,1,111,NULL,'2014-03-15 11:04:48' union all   Select 122,3,13,NULL,'2014-03-15 11:10:48'";
Query query=session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
query.executeUpdate();
```

**StackTrace :**

```
Query was empty.()
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)

com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)

com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate
(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:175)

org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate
(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:165)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1163)
org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:334)
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this?

After so many tried i found solution.

**Solved :**

```
Problem is queryString is passed in method and it generate dynamic query 
so sometimes   it only generate ';' in queryString so in MySql if hibernate found 
';' in session.creareSQLQuery(queryString) then it throws 'Query Was Empty' Exception.
```

Comment: Make sure your database allows null values.

Comment: yes it allow null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is queryString is passed in method and it generate dynamic query 
so sometimes   it only generate ';' in queryString so in MySql **If hibernate found 
';' in session.creareSQLQuery(queryString) then it throws 'Query Was Empty' Exception**

Answer (score 0):

Use following query

```
String queryString="INSERT INTO Mytable (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) Select 111,1,111,NULL,'2014-03-15 11:04:48' union all   Select 122,3,13,NULL,'2014-03-15 11:10:48'";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you post stacktrace?

Comment: I have posted stacktrace

Comment: Would require full stacktrace from start till end.

Comment: Try two different inserts rather than union all, if it helps.

Comment: I have tried this also still it gives error.I am using hibernate ,Is it possible that hibernate make query empty if something wrong in query?

Comment: If something is wrong in the query it gives a SQLGrammarException

Comment: Ok now you should post your table structure.

Comment: for once simply try following query INSERT INTO Mytable (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) values ( 111,1,111,NULL,'2014-03-15 11:04:48')

Comment: Or following query INSERT INTO Mytable (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) Select 111,1,111,NULL,'2014-03-15 11:04:48' from dual union all   Select 122,3,13,NULL,'2014-03-15 11:10:48' from dual";

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Mytable` (
  `field1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `field2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `field3` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `field4` bigint(20) NULL,
  `field5` datetime,
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM

Comment: Try 2 query variants I mentioned in my comments. See if they help.

Comment: Solved it.. the problem is my query is passed in method and sometime in query it passed only ';' so in MySql if hibernate found only ';' then it will throws Query Was Empty Exception